# Custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory

Tags: solr

I have written a custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory to parse my data before getting indexed. But the data is not getting committed. So when i restart the server all the data is gone. I have used the correct config also.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="mytestupdatehandler"  default="true">
   <processor class="com.solr.handler.interceptor"></processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>

<requestHandler name="/MypdateHandler" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" >
   <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="update.chain">mytestupdatehandler</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <!-- See below for information on defining 
     updateRequestProcessorChains that can be used by name 
     on each Update Request
     -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="maxThreads">50</str>     
        <str name="handlerType">asyncXML</str>
        <str name="sharedError">false</str>             
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Also the default update handler also uses my update.chain . how to prevent that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have **default="true"**, so that makes your chain used for all update handlers. Remove that.
2. You seem to be missing class name in your handler definition, unless it is **interceptor** in the **com.solr.handler** package: `<processor class="com.solr.handler.interceptor.CLASSNAME?"></processor>`
3. Are you getting any errors in the console log if you start Solr from the command line? That might give you a hint.

Comment: thanks a lot. I removed default=true and it is working now. there are no errors in log. it just that data is not getting committed. do i need to commit programmatically

Comment: Depending on how you submit and what your solrconfig.xml looks like (e.g. if you have autocommits), you may need to commit by hand. Have a look at post.jar in the examples directory, it allows you to issue a commit command.

Comment: i was not adding commit that is why it was not getting indexed. thanks a lot

Comment: one more thing. my commitwithin is not working. can that be because of any solr config. i have added commitwithin. but when i restart the data is lost. but when i use commit=true it works. what can be the problem

Comment: This would deserve a new separate question. Your configuration has changed and you want other people to have a fresh look at the issue you are facing.